# Change border thickness of textInput in error state in Flex?

Tags: apache-flex, border, thickness

I know you can change the errorColor of a textinput, but I'm searching for the possibility to change the thickness of that border on error.

It seems that the thin red line is not very noticeable, and I want to bring more
attention to fields which have errors.

Any Idea?

Answer (score 0):

To use the `borderThickness` attribute of a `TextInput`, you need to have the `borderStyle` set to `solid`.

```
        <mx:TextInput
            id="input"
            borderColor="red"
            borderThickness=2
            borderStyle="solid"
            />
```

Default `borderThickness` is `1`

Answer (score -1):

you can define your own@custom skin of error by using `errorSkin=""` in `textInput`. this is `errorskin` avilable in more component. you can learn more about [errorskin in adobe's help page](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/spark/skins/spark/ErrorSkin.html)

may this link will help you..

Comment: Thanks for ur response. i'm on Flex 3 SDK and as far i know errorSkin is for Flex 4. :(

Comment: you are right @Pierre, errorSkin is in Flex 4 but you can also change errortip skin by css in Flex 3. see
http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=tooltips_5.html

Comment: U r right but this only allow me to change the style of errortip. I just want to change the border thickness of the input on error and not the style of the tooltip.